# US Format Timestamp needed for application running on PCs in various countries .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime

I have an application that is running on PCs in several countries that needs to generate a US timestamp for a ORACLE SQL statement. Using Now() returns a suitable timestamp on a standard US PC running the application but that doesn't work if the computer is set up to use a different regions date/time format.

I tried using DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt") to generate the desired string but for some reason the string comes out with periods instead of slashes (periods are commonly used in the region this test was run in) between the month & day and day & year.

Example: The command above generates the string "10.26.2022 8:24:33 AM" instead of "10/26/2022 8:24:33 AM" as expected.

Comment: Why are you passing a *string* into the database at all? I'd expect the SQL to use a parameterized query and pass `DateTime.UtcNow` (better to use UTC for timestamps than local time) as the value.

Answer (score 1):

By default `DateTime.ToString` will use the language & culture information that's set on the computer that it's running on. The `/` is the [Date Separator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dateSeparator) and the `:` is the [Time Separator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#timeSeparator), both of these change depending on the culture.

To fix the difference in format there are two options:

1. [Escape the](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#escape) `/` and `:` characters so that they are the literal `/` and `:` characters rather than parsed as the Date Separator and Time Separator:

```
Dim dateString = DateTime.Now().ToString("MM\/dd\/yyyy h\:mm\:ss tt")
```

2. Explicitly set the culture that you want to use for formatting.
   Either by using the culture name:

```
Dim dateString = DateTime.Now().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))
```

Or by using the Locale ID (LCID). 1033 is en-US.

```
Dim dateString = DateTime.Now().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(1033))
```

You can get a list of culture names and LCIDs using

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultures(System.Globalization.CultureTypes.AllCultures)
```

---

There are also other solutions that don't directly answer your question.

1. Use the [Round Trip `O` format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-round-trip-o-o-format-specifier) which outputs the date in the ISO8601 format and is unambiguous.
2. Use a query parameter and pass in the DateTime directly, you won't need to format the date and it's safer (prevents SQL injection). How you do this will depend on the SQL library that you're using.
3. If the date is being stored then use a `DateTime` column (or equivalent) and the query parameter from #2.